# Not able to capture DV from my Panasonic camcorder to my computer

Tags: windows-xp, video-editing, video-capture, firewire

I have a Panasonic GS5 handycam, in which i recorded some videos which are stored in mini DVs.

Now i want those videos in my computer so I bought a Firewire capturing card and cable, installed the card in my computer with Windows XP, installed the Pinacle 9 software for capturing but as I started capturing, Pinacle showed a message that connect your camcorder

So, to check it, I took camera to someone else's computer who also have capturing card and it worked there perfectly but it isn't working on my system.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Does the software even support WinXP... most doesn't these days

Comment: @Tetsujin yes it supports however i also tried in window 7 but it is not working there also